# How to construct a perfect BST from an unbalanced BST with n elements (assuming that n=(2^i)-1, i is natural)

Tags: binary-search-trees

How do I construct a perfect BST from an unbalanced BST with $n$ elements (assuming that $n=2^i-1$, $i$ is natural). ** At the worst case of $O(n)$**.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is as follows: do a symmetric visit of the BST (in time $O(n)$) and write down the elements in increasing order to an array $A$. Then reconstruct the BST from $A$.

If you're fine with a recursive algorithm, and the positions of $A$ are indexed form $0$ to $n-1$, then the root $r$ of the new BST will be exactly the element $A[\frac{n-1}{2}]$. The elements in $A[0], \dots, A[\frac{n-1}{2}-1]$ will be those of the subtree $L$ rooted in the left child of $r$, and the elements in $A[\frac{n-1}{2}+1], \dots, A[n-1]$ will be in the subtree $R$ rooted in the right child of $r$.

Notice that $|L| = 1 + \frac{n-1}{2}-1 = \frac{2^i - 2}{2} = 2^{i-1}-1$ and 
$|R| = 1 + (n - 1) - (\frac{n-1}{2} + 1 ) =  (n - 1) - \frac{n-1}{2} = \frac{n-1}{2} = 2^{i-1}-1$, so you can apply this algorithm recursively.

The time required is $T(n) = T(2^i - 1) = 2 T(2^{i-1} - 1) + \Theta(1)$, with $T(1)=\Theta(1)$, which has solution $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.